# How to make Firefox auto launch at startup in fullscreen on Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, startup, firefox, fullscreen

## Firefox Ready

## Objective

I want my ubuntu to start and show a Duck Duck Go in fullscreen.

## Motivation

The first thing that I do on my PC is launch the Firefox and do stuff. For other stuff I hit the `ctrl+alt+T` and do things in the terminal. I want Firefox to start and be ready for me to work on.

## Ethics

Saving Time, Making the computer have a better workflow for a person like me [someone who spends most of his time using the browser], serving my laziness.

## Initial Hypothesis

I can make linux run Firefox using some commands at startup which will make it run in fullscreen and have opened the Duck Duck Go page.

## Updates

**20:56:44 15/08/18:** I am learning the commands available for Firefox from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options).

**21:12:15 15/08/18:** Done with commands. The command to start Firefox with default user and make it launch Duck Duck Go is `firefox “www.duckduckgo.com”`. I only need to find a way to make it open in fullscreen now.

**21:35:48 15/08/18:**  There is no way fullscreen launch can be performed using firefox’s commands. Neither does linux have any command to make Firefox launch in fullscreen. I might need to either send a keystroke F11 or use some plugin to accomplish this. But sending a keystore needs moe than one command and I don’t know if that will be as easy or not. And using a plugin is not favourable firstly because I don’t want every Firefox launch to be in fullscreen and secondly I don’t want to install another plugin.

**16/08/18**

**14:07:48**    I asked on stack exchange and someone suggested to use xdotool.

**14:22:17** I am learning xdotool

**14:56:18** The stack exchange command didnot work for me. What works for me instead is `xdotool search -class firefox key –-window %@ --delay 1000ms F11`.
 Now I am not able to give the command to launch firefox and use the xdotool in the same line. I need to learn bash.

**16:45:34 04/11/18:** Its been so long since I abandoned this project. Let me look at it agian, without revising on any of the updates and the old initial hypothesis.

**16:49:51 04/11/18:** just added this `firefox -url http://superuser.com &
xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --class "Firefox" windowactivate key F11` to startup application list. It did worked when I passed from the terminal though. Lets see if it works after restart. Will it work on logout and login? Lets see.

**16:54:54 04/11/18:**  It did took me into firefox with duckduckgo but it also tried to take me to the url f11. Maybe I need to tweak it a bit. Its actually ment for terminal and not for single line command which is need in startup application. BTW it did work with log out and in. Second try. This time I removed the ‘&’ from the previous command.

**16:58:17 04/11/18:** Still didn’t work!! Same issue. I guess I’ll try sending this log to someone inside firefox. Maybe they will be able to help.

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? GNOME? I believe each one has its own mechanism to auto-start apps.

Comment: Yes its gnome @glennjackman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a miniscript with xdotool:

```
#!/bin/sh
firefox &
xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --pid $! windowactivate key F11
```

Answer (score 1):

Partial Solution:

```
[install directory]\firefox.exe -kiosk http://www.duckduckgo.com
```

I randomly found this solution today. Firefox has this feature called [Firefox Kiosk](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-enterprise-kiosk-mode) since Firefox 71. It seems to be fully supported on Windows and conditionally supported on other OSs.

**What is Kiosk mode?**

Kiosk mode locks down Firefox in order to protect the kiosk from users. This is specifically relevant to, but not only limited to scenarios where the device is publicly accessed from libraries, vending machines or public transportation.

**Key characteristics of the Firefox Enterprise Kiosk**

- Runs in full screen mode by default
- menus, awesome bar and toolbar are not visible as well as tabs
- The X button is not available when you hover at the top of the screen
- F11 does not work
- The right-click context menu does not work
- Hides the status bar at the the bottom when attempting to indicate progress
- Hides the destination link when hovering over links
- Available on Windows

**Notes for use on other OSs:**

**macOS**: Kiosk mode runs on macOS although the system menu cannot be disabled (limitation from Apple)
**Linux**: Kiosk mode runs on Linux if the OS doesn't use a unified menu

**Why I consider this solution partial?**

The initial requirement was for Firefox to be ready for the user and not to present a restrictive environment for the user. Minus all the restrictions, the kiosk presents the setup required.